# Keep all style of page inside page block element

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass, vuejs2

I have this code :

```
<div class="page-payment">
  <div class="payment-methods" v-if="!pending">
    <sepa-modal
      ref="sepaModal"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

`SepaModal.vue` :

```
<b-modal
id="sepaModal"
centered
top
no-fade
size="md"
ref="modal"
hide-footer
@show="showPopup"
@hidden="closePopup"
>
  <template #modal-header-close>
    <icon width="20" height="20" class="d-none d-md-block" type="times"/>
    <icon width="10" height="18" class="d-md-none" type="arrow-left"/>
  </template>
  <template #modal-title>
  </template>
  <div>
    <div class="content-modal content-modal-sepa">
      <div class="modal-header"></div>
      ..........
    </div>
  </div>
```

The .css :

```
.page-payment {
   .payment-methods {
       .content-modal {
           padding: 20px !important
       }
   }
}
```

The style is not getting into account. But I want to keep all styles inside: `.page-payment{}`. How can I solve it?

Comment: Do you have scss enabled in your project? Are you using Vue CLI? Do you have the appropriate `lang` tag on your style block?

Comment: yes,yes,yes.....